# python pep 8 80 limit white space

Tags: python, pep8

I want to keep this line of code under 79 characters.

```
return str('<' + student_number + ',' + name + ',' + str(age) + ',' + str(enrolled) + '>')
```

I want to do this without leaving any whitespace, when indenting

Comment: Err... great. This kind of things would be more like [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, don't concatenate string with `+`, use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 79 characters including the 4 white space indentation.

```
    return '<' + student_number + ',' + name + ',' + str(age) + ',' + str(enrolled) + '>'
```

Per your initial construct:

- student_number must contain a string
- the outer `str()` was not useful

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is from a function so you do need to indent it by 4, leaving only 75 usable spaces.
How about something like:

```
return str('<' + student_number + ',' + name + ',' + str(age) + 
           ',' + str(enrolled) + '>')
```

But I think it's better to use string formatting:

```
return str('<%s,%s,%s,%s>' % (student_number, name, age, enrolled))
```

and as cdarke indicated, no outer str() is needed really:

```
return '<%s,%s,%s,%s>' % (student_number, name, age, enrolled)
```

Comment: Why the outer `str()`?